# overriding partially an numpy array does not work

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I tried to override a numpy array partially

[image]

does anyone know how to do that in such comfort indexing way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Setup***

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]])
b = np.array([[888,888], [99, 99]])
```

---

You are operating on a copy of the array, so the modifications are not persisted, use [`numpy.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) here:

```
>>> a[np.ix_([1,2], [0,1])] = b
>>> a
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [888, 888,   1],
       [ 99,  99,   1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this sort of indexing with the `:` separating your starting and ending indices:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]])
# 1: and :2 all_indices_after_1 and all_indices_before_2 respectively
>>> a[1:,:2] = np.array([[888,888], [99, 99]])
>>> a
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [888, 888,   1],
       [ 99,  99,   1]])
```